# Storm is crashing due to zookeeper status changing

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-kafka

I have very basic storm topology which contains 1 unreliable spout + 1 bolt. Spout is fed by Kafka broker via zookeeper. The Spout sends tuples to a bolt witch in its role do nothing ( has empty execute method).
The topology run in local cluster mode and it crashes after a while from run.
I tried to increase the app memory by -Xmx parameter many times, but the problem still appears.
please help!
Here is the code snippet that build the topology:

```
builder.setSpout("kafka_forwarding_spout", new KafkaForwardingSpout(),1);
      builder.setBolt("fake_bolt", new FakeBolt(),1).localOrShuffleGrouping("kafka_forwarding_spout");
```

Here is a snippet from storm log:

```
1318482 [Thread-37-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
1319574 [CuratorFramework-9] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST
1312307 [Thread-39-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
1307441 [Thread-25-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
1227216 [Thread-29-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
1191153 [Thread-31-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
1771836 [Thread-39-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
1688630 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
1650422 [Thread-35-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
1635500 [Thread-19-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
1616369 [CuratorFramework-11] ERROR com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Background exception was not retry-able or retry gave up
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
  at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl.performBackgroundOperation(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:39) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.OperationAndData.callPerformBackgroundOperation(OperationAndData.java:40) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:547) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$200(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:50) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:177) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_05]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
1617025 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2001] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x149dd7eb6a2000b, likely client has closed socket
1600212 [Thread-23-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
1584086 [Thread-21-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
1570224 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down receive thread
1569786 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
2158302 [Thread-5] ERROR backtype.storm.event - Error when processing event
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
  at backtype.storm.util$wrap_in_runtime.invoke(util.clj:44) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$get_children.invoke(zookeeper.clj:133) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__2385.get_children(cluster.clj:101) ~[na:na]
  at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2814.assignments(cluster.clj:243) ~[na:na]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$assignments_snapshot.invoke(supervisor.clj:39) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__6251.invoke(supervisor.clj:298) ~[na:na]
  at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2921.invoke(event.clj:39) ~[na:na]
  at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
  at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:180) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:173) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:85) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:169) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:161) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:36) ~[curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$get_children.invoke(zookeeper.clj:131) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
  ... 13 common frames omitted
2117747 [Thread-4] ERROR com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Connection timed out
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
  at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) [curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:149) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:138) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:85) [curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:134) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:125) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:34) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_$fn__2170.invoke(zookeeper.clj:96) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_.invoke(zookeeper.clj:93) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$mkdirs.invoke(zookeeper.clj:107) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__2385.set_ephemeral_node(cluster.clj:69) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2814.supervisor_heartbeat_BANG_(cluster.clj:315) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$eval6298$exec_fn__1459__auto____6299$heartbeat_fn__6301.invoke(supervisor.clj:378) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.timer$schedule_recurring$this__2141.invoke(timer.clj:92) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__2124$fn__2125.invoke(timer.clj:48) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__2124.invoke(timer.clj:41) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
2078727 [Thread-16] ERROR com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Connection timed out
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
  at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) [curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:149) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:138) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:85) [curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:134) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:125) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:34) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_$fn__2170.invoke(zookeeper.clj:96) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_.invoke(zookeeper.clj:93) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists.invoke(zookeeper.clj:141) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__2385.set_data(cluster.clj:85) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2814.worker_heartbeat_BANG_(cluster.clj:291) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$do_executor_heartbeats.doInvoke(worker.clj:53) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$eval5665$exec_fn__1459__auto____5666$fn__5669.invoke(worker.clj:367) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.timer$schedule_recurring$this__2141.invoke(timer.clj:92) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__2124$fn__2125.invoke(timer.clj:48) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__2124.invoke(timer.clj:41) [na:0.9.1-incubating]
  at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
2079838 [CuratorFramework-11] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST
2052508 [Thread-37-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
1948998 [yassin-long-d_localhost.localdomain-1416760311632-aa3d627e_watcher_executor] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector - [yassin-long-d_localhost.localdomain-1416760311632-aa3d627e], exception during rebalance 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.readData(ZkConnection.java:103) ~[zkclient-0.3.jar:0.3]
  at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$9.call(ZkClient.java:770) ~[zkclient-0.3.jar:0.3]
  at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$9.call(ZkClient.java:766) ~[zkclient-0.3.jar:0.3]
  at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:675) ~[zkclient-0.3.jar:0.3]
  at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:766) ~[zkclient-0.3.jar:0.3]
  at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:761) ~[zkclient-0.3.jar:0.3]
  at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.readData(ZkUtils.scala:461) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar:na]
  at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getCluster$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:505) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar:na]
  at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getCluster$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:504) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar:na]
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) ~[scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) ~[scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72) ~[scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54) ~[scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
  at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.getCluster(ZkUtils.scala:504) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar:na]
  at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:407) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar:na]
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
  at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:402) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar:na]
  at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anon$1.run(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:355) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar:na]
1872056 [Thread-39-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
1853312 [Thread-35-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
1840380 [Thread-31-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
1808599 [Thread-41-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
1799622 [Thread-25-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
2287292 [Thread-41-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
2287075 [Thread-37-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
2286862 [yassin-long-d_localhost.localdomain-1416760311632-aa3d627e_watcher_executor] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector - [yassin-long-d_localhost.localdomain-1416760311632-aa3d627e], end rebalancing consumer yassin-long-d_localhost.localdomain-1416760311632-aa3d627e try #0
2280400 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2001] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x149dd7eb6a20005, likely client has closed socket
2280180 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
2267345 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Shutting down receiving-thread: [events_topology-1-1416760309, 1027]
2242225 [Thread-19-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
2224569 [Thread-29-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
2226559 [Thread-21-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
2209276 [Thread-23-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
2296607 [Thread-41-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
2293718 [Thread-37-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Expired)
2292830 [Thread-25-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
2498572 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2001] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x149dd7eb6a20003, likely client has closed socket
2540517 [Thread-41-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Error while calling watcher 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main-SendThread(localhost:2001)"
2637439 [Thread-35-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
2647739 [Thread-39-kafka_forwarding_spout-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (Disconnected)
2672605 [main-SendThread(localhost:2001)] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - from main-SendThread(localhost:2001)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2764243 [Thread-25-kafka_forwarding_spout-SendThread(zoo2:2182)] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - from Thread-25-kafka_forwarding_spout-SendThread(zoo2:2182)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2720032 [main-SendThread(localhost:2001)] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - from main-SendThread(localhost:2001)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2731157 [Thread-8] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Thread Thread[Thread-8,5,main] died
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2800693 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2001] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Thread Thread[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2001,5,main] died
```

Comment: Is your FakeBolt completely empty? I'd suggest you try sending something in it, even if you don't do any transformation to the data.

Comment: @lrnzcig thank you for your reply ,I already did what you say but the problem still occurs.

Comment: what are you using to launch it? Just java, eclipse? How long does it take for the memory error to happen? What is the content of KafkaForwardingSpout(), is it a class that you have build yourself?

Comment: Here is the command line that I use to lunch storm: 
bin/storm jar yassin-storm.jar -Xmx50g com.yassin.storm.EventsTopology
regarding how long does it take, storm consumes many events from Kafka before crashing, it consumes around 3000 events, as you may know it should consume millions of events per minute, after consuming that events it stops consuming and the warnings start appear (warning about zookeeper status changes) till out of memory error finally appears, please note that as I am montiring storm process via htop, I notice that storm process used memory is increasing rapidly.

Comment: regarding KafkaForwardingSpout class , yes I built it myself, it contains very simple code also , I just open connection to kafka broker and in nextTuple() method I emit evets or sleep for a while to give bolt some time to finish processing (in this case the bolt do nothing)

Comment: Weird! Well, you don't need to allocate 50g, I guess your computer does not have so much memory anyway! What do you see in the memory monitor? Your process consumes all the memory available in the computer? Anyway, I guess you have tried all the more or less obvious things by now. I'd suggest you generate a dump from your crash and analyze it. You launch your process like this: java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms40m -Xmx4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and you'll get a huge file with your data. Then try to analyze then what is occupying so much memory, e.g. using eclipse.

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a java heap size problem. Check there are many other configurable memory related parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is being caused due to the Java Virtual Machine running out of available Heap memory in the system. Depending on on which underlying operating system that you are using, you can use the `-Xmx` parameter followed by the amount of memory you want to allocate. For example, if you want to allocate 2GB of memory then you need to mention `-Xms2048m` and the maximum heap size to be set as `-Xmx2048m`. However, remember that increasing the heap size after getting an `OutofMemoryError` is generally a short-term solution and it is highly probable to occur again in the future. It is generally an indicator  for optimising your code to be memory efficient.